# Python determine if time is between two hours in variables

Tags: python

```
settingsNightStart = settings[28]
settingsNightStop = settings[29]


if datetime.time(settingsNightStart) <= datetime.time.now() <= datetime.time(settingsNightStop):
    Night = 1
```

I have two variables coming from a database that users store there starting time and ending time in 24 hr format (0-23).  Is there a better way to store this setting from the user?

I need to figure out how determine if the current time is between those two times.  Most of the time it's going to need to be determined over night where the users time will be starting at 8PM and ending at 7AM.  When I run the script I need to know if the current time is between those hours.  I don't know if datetime can work with what I'm trying to do?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What exactly is the time format?  If you just have 2 numbers representing hours (without day information), it could be argued that any number (I guess within the accepted range of numbers -- 0 -> 23) is between them...

Comment: I edited the question.  Thanks

Comment: You could likely determine this in the database itself. MySQL has `NOW()` for this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose you have `start_hour` and `stop_hour`:

`this_hour = datetime.now().hour
if start_hour > stop_hour:
   night = start_hour < this_hour or this_hour < stop_hour
else:
   night = start_hour < this_hour < stop_hour`